# Cannot load YAML jar resources

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

Im trying to load a .yml file from my Jar's resources folder. The line where I retrieve it ( Line 33: `input = new FileInputStream(new URL(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Resources/devConfig.yml").getFile()).getPath());`)

throws a NullPointerException.

```
private static void createMap() {
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(new URL(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/Resources/devConfig.yml").getFile()).getPath());   
    } catch (/*FileNotFoundException*/ Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    try{
    Map l = (Map) yaml.load(input);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getDevConfig.map = (Map) yaml.load(input);
}
```

I'm using the [snakeYaml](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) library.

in the same project I have this (almost) exact code to load a YAML file that's external to the Jar, the only difference being `input` is loaded like this:  `new FileInputStream(new File("path_to_folder" + filename));`

the exceptions I'm getting:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at util.getDevConfig.createMap(getDevConfig.java:33)
    at util.getDevConfig.getKey(getDevConfig.java:48)`

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:200)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.<init>(StreamReader.java:60)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:412)
at util.getDevConfig.createMap(getDevConfig.java:43)
at util.getDevConfig.getKey(getDevConfig.java:52)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(PushbackInputStream.java:74)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:166)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.init(UnicodeReader.java:90)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:122)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:184)
```

My question is very simple: Why am I getting a null pointer exception?

Comment: Try `input = ClassLoader.....getResourceAsStream(...);`

Comment: @peeskillet would I still need to say `new FileInputStream()` ?

Comment: No.... and no `getFile().getPath()`

Comment: @peeskillet Tried it... still getting the exception

Comment: Is `Resources` at the root of the classpath (`src/Resources`, with Maven `src/main/resources/Resources`)? Try it without the `/` in the path.

Comment: @peeskillet I have other things in the same folder that are accessed successfully, and they use the same folder path.